# Create text area (textEdit) with line number in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5, qtextedit

I want to create textEdit with line number on the left side in PyQt like Notepad++. I tried this adding another textEdit but scrolling is stuck. I searched and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17424032/line-numbering-of-a-textedit-in-pyqt), but there is no good solution for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeEditor example in pyqt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243852/codeeditor-example-in-pyqt)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for [CodeEditor example in pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243852/codeeditor-example-in-pyqt) based on the c++ http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-codeeditor-example.html

Putting it together for python3 (Im using PyQt4 not 5 but I guess it is similar) (and using QPlainTextEdit not QTextEdit see [QTextEdit vs QPlainTextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466046/qtextedit-vs-qplaintextedit) ):

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

import numpy as np

class LineNumberArea(QWidget):


    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__(editor)
        self.myeditor = editor


    def sizeHint(self):
        return Qsize(self.editor.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0)


    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.myeditor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(event)


class CodeEditor(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lineNumberArea = LineNumberArea(self)

        self.connect(self, SIGNAL('blockCountChanged(int)'), self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth)
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL('updateRequest(QRect,int)'), self.updateLineNumberArea)
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL('cursorPositionChanged()'), self.highlightCurrentLine)

        self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)


    def lineNumberAreaWidth(self):
        digits = 1
        count = max(1, self.blockCount())
        while count >= 10:
            count /= 10
            digits += 1
        space = 3 + self.fontMetrics().width('9') * digits
        return space


    def updateLineNumberAreaWidth(self, _):
        self.setViewportMargins(self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0, 0, 0)


    def updateLineNumberArea(self, rect, dy):

        if dy:
            self.lineNumberArea.scroll(0, dy)
        else:
            self.lineNumberArea.update(0, rect.y(), self.lineNumberArea.width(),
                       rect.height())

        if rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()):
            self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)


    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)

        cr = self.contentsRect();
        self.lineNumberArea.setGeometry(QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(),
                    self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()))


    def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
        mypainter = QPainter(self.lineNumberArea)

        mypainter.fillRect(event.rect(), Qt.lightGray)

        block = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        blockNumber = block.blockNumber()
        top = self.blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(self.contentOffset()).top()
        bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()

        # Just to make sure I use the right font
        height = self.fontMetrics().height()
        while block.isValid() and (top <= event.rect().bottom()):
            if block.isVisible() and (bottom >= event.rect().top()):
                number = str(blockNumber + 1)
                mypainter.setPen(Qt.black)
                mypainter.drawText(0, top, self.lineNumberArea.width(), height,
                 Qt.AlignRight, number)

            block = block.next()
            top = bottom
            bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
            blockNumber += 1


    def highlightCurrentLine(self):
        extraSelections = []

        if not self.isReadOnly():
            selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()

            lineColor = QColor(Qt.yellow).lighter(160)

            selection.format.setBackground(lineColor)
            selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat.FullWidthSelection, True)
            selection.cursor = self.textCursor()
            selection.cursor.clearSelection()
            extraSelections.append(selection)
        self.setExtraSelections(extraSelections)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    txt = CodeEditor()
    txt.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5):

It's my code of PyQt5 and python3 which combined @Dan-Dev and @Axel Schneider. You can directly run it, or simply import use code `from QCodeEditor import QCodeEditor`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# QcodeEditor.py by acbetter.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect, QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPlainTextEdit, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QPainter, QTextFormat


class QLineNumberArea(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, editor):
        super().__init__(editor)
        self.codeEditor = editor

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(self.editor.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        self.codeEditor.lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(event)


class QCodeEditor(QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.lineNumberArea = QLineNumberArea(self)
        self.blockCountChanged.connect(self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth)
        self.updateRequest.connect(self.updateLineNumberArea)
        self.cursorPositionChanged.connect(self.highlightCurrentLine)
        self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def lineNumberAreaWidth(self):
        digits = 1
        max_value = max(1, self.blockCount())
        while max_value >= 10:
            max_value /= 10
            digits += 1
        space = 3 + self.fontMetrics().width('9') * digits
        return space

    def updateLineNumberAreaWidth(self, _):
        self.setViewportMargins(self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), 0, 0, 0)

    def updateLineNumberArea(self, rect, dy):
        if dy:
            self.lineNumberArea.scroll(0, dy)
        else:
            self.lineNumberArea.update(0, rect.y(), self.lineNumberArea.width(), rect.height())
        if rect.contains(self.viewport().rect()):
            self.updateLineNumberAreaWidth(0)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        cr = self.contentsRect()
        self.lineNumberArea.setGeometry(QRect(cr.left(), cr.top(), self.lineNumberAreaWidth(), cr.height()))

    def highlightCurrentLine(self):
        extraSelections = []
        if not self.isReadOnly():
            selection = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
            lineColor = QColor(Qt.yellow).lighter(160)
            selection.format.setBackground(lineColor)
            selection.format.setProperty(QTextFormat.FullWidthSelection, True)
            selection.cursor = self.textCursor()
            selection.cursor.clearSelection()
            extraSelections.append(selection)
        self.setExtraSelections(extraSelections)

    def lineNumberAreaPaintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self.lineNumberArea)

        painter.fillRect(event.rect(), Qt.lightGray)

        block = self.firstVisibleBlock()
        blockNumber = block.blockNumber()
        top = self.blockBoundingGeometry(block).translated(self.contentOffset()).top()
        bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()

        # Just to make sure I use the right font
        height = self.fontMetrics().height()
        while block.isValid() and (top <= event.rect().bottom()):
            if block.isVisible() and (bottom >= event.rect().top()):
                number = str(blockNumber + 1)
                painter.setPen(Qt.black)
                painter.drawText(0, top, self.lineNumberArea.width(), height, Qt.AlignRight, number)

            block = block.next()
            top = bottom
            bottom = top + self.blockBoundingRect(block).height()
            blockNumber += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    codeEditor = QCodeEditor()
    codeEditor.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It runs like this.

[image: QCodeEditor]

By the way, if you want use it in your Qt Designer, you should do it like this and place the *.ui file in the same directory of your QCodeEditor.py file's path unless you set the environment variable. And, you need convert your *.ui file to *.py file by the command `pyuic5 -x *.ui -o *.py`. Hope Helpful~

[image: QCodeEditor in Qt Designer]

Answer (score 3):

here a version for PyQt5 (with Menu etc ...)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -- coding: utf-8 --

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPlainTextEdit, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QHBoxLayout, \
                         QFrame, QTextEdit, QToolBar, QComboBox, QLabel, QAction, QLineEdit, QToolButton, QMenu, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPainter, QTextFormat, QColor, QTextCursor, QKeySequence, QClipboard, QTextCharFormat, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QVariant, QRect, QDir, QFile, QFileInfo, QTextStream, QRegExp, QSettings
import sys, os

lineBarColor = QColor("#ACDED5")
lineHighlightColor  = QColor("#ACDED5")

class NumberBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(NumberBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.editor = parent
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.editor.blockCountChanged.connect(self.update_width)
        self.editor.updateRequest.connect(self.update_on_scroll)
        self.update_width('1')

    def update_on_scroll(self, rect, scroll):
        if self.isVisible():
            if scroll:
                self.scroll(0, scroll)
            else:
                self.update()

    def update_width(self, string):
        width = self.fontMetrics().width(str(string)) + 10
        if self.width() != width:
            self.setFixedWidth(width)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.isVisible():
            block = self.editor.firstVisibleBlock()
            height = self.fontMetrics().height()
            number = block.blockNumber()
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.fillRect(event.rect(), lineBarColor)
            painter.drawRect(0, 0, event.rect().width() - 1, event.rect().height() - 1)
            font = painter.font()

            current_block = self.editor.textCursor().block().blockNumber() + 1

            condition = True
            while block.isValid() and condition:
                block_geometry = self.editor.blockBoundingGeometry(block)
                offset = self.editor.contentOffset()
                block_top = block_geometry.translated(offset).top()
                number += 1

                rect = QRect(0, block_top, self.width() - 5, height)

                if number == current_block:
                    font.setBold(True)
                else:
                    font.setBold(False)

                painter.setFont(font)
                painter.drawText(rect, Qt.AlignRight, '%i'%number)

                if block_top > event.rect().bottom():
                    condition = False

                block = block.next()

            painter.end()

class myEditor(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(myEditor, self).__init__(parent)
        self.MaxRecentFiles = 5
        self.windowList = []
        self.recentFileActs = []
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        # Editor Widget ...
        QIcon.setThemeName('Faenza-Dark')
        self.editor = QPlainTextEdit() 
        self.editor.setStyleSheet(stylesheet2(self))
        self.editor.setFrameStyle(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.editor.setTabStopWidth(14)
        self.extra_selections = []
        self.fname = ""
        self.filename = ""
        # Line Numbers ...
        self.numbers = NumberBar(self.editor)

        self.createActions()
        # Laying out...
        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.setSpacing(1.5)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.numbers)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.editor)

        ### begin toolbar
        tb = QToolBar(self)
        tb.setWindowTitle("File Toolbar")        

        self.newAct = QAction("&New", self, shortcut=QKeySequence.New,
                statusTip="Create a new file", triggered=self.newFile)
        self.newAct.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("document-new"))

        self.openAct = QAction("&Open", self, shortcut=QKeySequence.Open,
                statusTip="open file", triggered=self.openFile)
        self.openAct.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("document-open"))

        self.saveAct = QAction("&Save", self, shortcut=QKeySequence.Save,
                statusTip="save file", triggered=self.fileSave)
        self.saveAct.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("document-save"))

        self.saveAsAct = QAction("&Save as ...", self, shortcut=QKeySequence.SaveAs,
                statusTip="save file as ...", triggered=self.fileSaveAs)
        self.saveAsAct.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("document-save-as"))

        self.exitAct = QAction("Exit", self, shortcut=QKeySequence.Quit,
                toolTip="Exit", triggered=self.handleQuit)
        self.exitAct.setIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("application-exit"))

        ### find / replace toolbar
        self.tbf = QToolBar(self)
        self.tbf.setWindowTitle("Find Toolbar")   
        self.findfield = QLineEdit()
        self.findfield.addAction(QIcon.fromTheme("edit-find"), QLineEdit.LeadingPosition)
        self.findfield.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.findfield.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.findfield.setPlaceholderText("find")
        self.findfield.setToolTip("press RETURN to find")
        self.findfield.setText("")
        ft = self.findfield.text()
        self.findfield.returnPressed.connect(self.findText)
        self.tbf.addWidget(self.findfield)
        self.replacefield = QLineEdit()
        self.replacefield.addAction(QIcon.fromTheme("edit-find-and-replace"), QLineEdit.LeadingPosition)
        self.replacefield.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.replacefield.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.replacefield.setPlaceholderText("replace with")
        self.replacefield.setToolTip("press RETURN to replace the first")
        self.replacefield.returnPressed.connect(self.replaceOne)
        self.tbf.addSeparator() 
        self.tbf.addWidget(self.replacefield)
        self.tbf.addSeparator()

        self.tbf.addAction("replace all", self.replaceAll)
        self.tbf.addSeparator()

        layoutV = QVBoxLayout()

        bar=self.menuBar()

        self.filemenu=bar.addMenu("File")
        self.separatorAct = self.filemenu.addSeparator()
        self.filemenu.addAction(self.newAct)
        self.filemenu.addAction(self.openAct)
        self.filemenu.addAction(self.saveAct)
        self.filemenu.addAction(self.saveAsAct)
        self.filemenu.addSeparator()
        for i in range(self.MaxRecentFiles):
            self.filemenu.addAction(self.recentFileActs[i])
        self.updateRecentFileActions()
        self.filemenu.addSeparator()
        self.filemenu.addAction(self.exitAct)
        bar.setStyleSheet(stylesheet2(self))
        editmenu = bar.addMenu("Edit")
        editmenu.addAction(QAction(QIcon.fromTheme('edit-copy'), "Copy", self, triggered = self.editor.copy, shortcut = QKeySequence.Copy))
        editmenu.addAction(QAction(QIcon.fromTheme('edit-cut'), "Cut", self, triggered = self.editor.cut, shortcut = QKeySequence.Cut))
        editmenu.addAction(QAction(QIcon.fromTheme('edit-paste'), "Paste", self, triggered = self.editor.paste, shortcut = QKeySequence.Paste))
        editmenu.addAction(QAction(QIcon.fromTheme('edit-delete'), "Delete", self, triggered = self.editor.cut, shortcut = QKeySequence.Delete))
        editmenu.addSeparator()
        editmenu.addAction(QAction(QIcon.fromTheme('edit-select-all'), "Select All", self, triggered = self.editor.selectAll, shortcut = QKeySequence.SelectAll))

        layoutV.addWidget(bar)      
        layoutV.addWidget(self.tbf)
        layoutV.addLayout(layoutH)

        ### main window
        mq = QWidget(self)
        mq.setLayout(layoutV)
        self.setCentralWidget(mq)

        # Event Filter ...
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        self.editor.setFocus()
        self.cursor = QTextCursor()
        self.editor.setPlainText("hello")
        self.editor.moveCursor(self.cursor.End)
        self.editor.document().modificationChanged.connect(self.setWindowModified)

        # Brackets ExtraSelection ...
        self.left_selected_bracket  = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
        self.right_selected_bracket = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()

    def createActions(self):
        for i in range(self.MaxRecentFiles):
            self.recentFileActs.append(
                   QAction(self, visible=False,
                            triggered=self.openRecentFile))


    def openRecentFile(self):
        action = self.sender()
        if action:
            if (self.maybeSave()):
                self.openFileOnStart(action.data())

        ### New File
    def newFile(self):
        if self.maybeSave():
            self.editor.clear()
            self.editor.setPlainText("")
            self.filename = ""
            self.setModified(False)
            self.editor.moveCursor(self.cursor.End)

       ### open File
    def openFileOnStart(self, path=None):
        if path:
            inFile = QFile(path)
            if inFile.open(QFile.ReadWrite | QFile.Text):
                text = inFile.readAll()

                try:
                        # Python v3.
                    text = str(text, encoding = 'utf8')
                except TypeError:
                        # Python v2.
                    text = str(text)
                self.editor.setPlainText(text)
                self.filename = path
                self.setModified(False)
                self.fname = QFileInfo(path).fileName() 
                self.setWindowTitle(self.fname + "[*]")
                self.document = self.editor.document()
                self.setCurrentFile(self.filename)

        ### open File
    def openFile(self, path=None):
        if self.maybeSave():
            if not path:
                path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", QDir.homePath() + "/Documents/",
                    "Text Files (*.txt *.csv *.py);;All Files (*.*)")

            if path:
                inFile = QFile(path)
                if inFile.open(QFile.ReadWrite | QFile.Text):
                    text = inFile.readAll()

                    try:
                        # Python v3.
                        text = str(text, encoding = 'utf8')
                    except TypeError:
                        # Python v2.
                        text = str(text)
                    self.editor.setPlainText(text)
                    self.filename = path
                    self.setModified(False)
                    self.fname = QFileInfo(path).fileName() 
                    self.setWindowTitle(self.fname + "[*]")
                    self.document = self.editor.document()
                    self.setCurrentFile(self.filename)

    def fileSave(self):
        if (self.filename != ""):
            file = QFile(self.filename)
            print(self.filename)
            if not file.open( QFile.WriteOnly | QFile.Text):
                QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error",
                        "Cannot write file %s:\n%s." % (self.filename, file.errorString()))
                return

            outstr = QTextStream(file)
            QApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)
            outstr << self.editor.toPlainText()
            QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()                
            self.setModified(False)
            self.fname = QFileInfo(self.filename).fileName() 
            self.setWindowTitle(self.fname + "[*]")
            self.setCurrentFile(self.filename)


        else:
            self.fileSaveAs()

            ### save File
    def fileSaveAs(self):
        fn, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save as...", self.filename,
                "Python files (*.py)")

        if not fn:
            print("Error saving")
            return False

        lfn = fn.lower()
        if not lfn.endswith('.py'):
            fn += '.py'

        self.filename = fn
        self.fname = os.path.splitext(str(fn))[0].split("/")[-1]
        return self.fileSave()

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        if self.maybeSave():
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore()

        ### ask to save
    def maybeSave(self):
        if not self.isModified():
            return True

        if self.filename.startswith(':/'):
            return True

        ret = QMessageBox.question(self, "Message",
                "<h4><p>The document was modified.</p>\n" \
                "<p>Do you want to save changes?</p></h4>",
                QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Cancel)

        if ret == QMessageBox.Yes:
            if self.filename == "":
                self.fileSaveAs()
                return False
            else:
                self.fileSave()
                return True

        if ret == QMessageBox.Cancel:
            return False

        return True   

    def findText(self):
        ft = self.findfield.text()
        if self.editor.find(ft):
            return
        else:
            self.editor.moveCursor(1)
            if self.editor.find(ft):
                self.editor.moveCursor(QTextCursor.Start, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)

    def handleQuit(self):
        print("Goodbye ...")
        app.quit()

    def set_numbers_visible(self, value = True):
        self.numbers.setVisible(False)

    def match_left(self, block, character, start, found):
        map = {'{': '}', '(': ')', '[': ']'}

        while block.isValid():
            data = block.userData()
            if data is not None:
                braces = data.braces
                N = len(braces)

                for k in range(start, N):
                    if braces[k].character == character:
                        found += 1

                    if braces[k].character == map[character]:
                        if not found:
                            return braces[k].position + block.position()
                        else:
                            found -= 1

                block = block.next()
                start = 0

    def match_right(self, block, character, start, found):
        map = {'}': '{', ')': '(', ']': '['}

        while block.isValid():
            data = block.userData()

            if data is not None:
                braces = data.braces

                if start is None:
                    start = len(braces)
                for k in range(start - 1, -1, -1):
                    if braces[k].character == character:
                        found += 1
                    if braces[k].character == map[character]:
                        if found == 0:
                            return braces[k].position + block.position()
                        else:
                            found -= 1
            block = block.previous()
            start = None
#    '''

        cursor = self.editor.textCursor()
        block = cursor.block()
        data = block.userData()
        previous, next = None, None

        if data is not None:
            position = cursor.position()
            block_position = cursor.block().position()
            braces = data.braces
            N = len(braces)

            for k in range(0, N):
                if braces[k].position == position - block_position or braces[k].position == position - block_position - 1:
                    previous = braces[k].position + block_position
                    if braces[k].character in ['{', '(', '[']:
                        next = self.match_left(block,
                                               braces[k].character,
                                               k + 1, 0)
                    elif braces[k].character in ['}', ')', ']']:
                        next = self.match_right(block,
                                                braces[k].character,
                                                k, 0)
                    if next is None:
                        next = -1

        if next is not None and next > 0:
            if next == 0 and next >= 0:
                format = QTextCharFormat()

            cursor.setPosition(previous)
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCharacter,
                                QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)

            format.setBackground(QColor('white'))
            self.left_selected_bracket.format = format
            self.left_selected_bracket.cursor = cursor

            cursor.setPosition(next)
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.NextCharacter,
                                QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)

            format.setBackground(QColor('white'))
            self.right_selected_bracket.format = format
            self.right_selected_bracket.cursor = cursor
#            '''
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        highlighted_line = QTextEdit.ExtraSelection()
        highlighted_line.format.setBackground(lineHighlightColor)
        highlighted_line.format.setProperty(QTextFormat
                                                 .FullWidthSelection,
                                                  QVariant(True))
        highlighted_line.cursor = self.editor.textCursor()
        highlighted_line.cursor.clearSelection()
        self.editor.setExtraSelections([highlighted_line,
                                      self.left_selected_bracket,
                                      self.right_selected_bracket])

    def document(self):
        return self.editor.document

    def isModified(self):
        return self.editor.document().isModified()

    def setModified(self, modified):
        self.editor.document().setModified(modified)

    def setLineWrapMode(self, mode):
        self.editor.setLineWrapMode(mode)

    def clear(self):
        self.editor.clear()

    def setPlainText(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.editor.setPlainText(*args, **kwargs)

    def setDocumentTitle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.editor.setDocumentTitle(*args, **kwargs)

    def set_number_bar_visible(self, value):
        self.numbers.setVisible(value)

    def replaceAll(self):
        print("replacing all")
        oldtext = self.editor.document().toPlainText()
        newtext = oldtext.replace(self.findfield.text(), self.replacefield.text())
        self.editor.setPlainText(newtext)
        self.setModified(True)

    def replaceOne(self):
        print("replacing all")
        oldtext = self.editor.document().toPlainText()
        newtext = oldtext.replace(self.findfield.text(), self.replacefield.text(), 1)
        self.editor.setPlainText(newtext)
        self.setModified(True)

    def setCurrentFile(self, fileName):
        self.curFile = fileName
        if self.curFile:
            self.setWindowTitle("%s - Recent Files" % self.strippedName(self.curFile))
        else:
            self.setWindowTitle("Recent Files")

        settings = QSettings('Axel Schneider', 'PTEdit')
        files = settings.value('recentFileList')

        try:
            files.remove(fileName)
        except ValueError:
            pass

        files.insert(0, fileName)
        del files[self.MaxRecentFiles:]

        settings.setValue('recentFileList', files)

        for widget in QApplication.topLevelWidgets():
            if isinstance(widget, myEditor):
                widget.updateRecentFileActions()

    def updateRecentFileActions(self):
        mytext = ""
        settings = QSettings('Axel Schneider', 'PTEdit')
        files = settings.value('recentFileList')

        numRecentFiles = min(len(files), self.MaxRecentFiles)

        for i in range(numRecentFiles):
            text = "&%d %s" % (i + 1, self.strippedName(files[i]))
            self.recentFileActs[i].setText(text)
            self.recentFileActs[i].setData(files[i])
            self.recentFileActs[i].setVisible(True)

        for j in range(numRecentFiles, self.MaxRecentFiles):
            self.recentFileActs[j].setVisible(False)

        self.separatorAct.setVisible((numRecentFiles > 0))

    def clearRecentFileList(self, fileName):
        self.rmenu.clear()


    def strippedName(self, fullFileName):
        return QFileInfo(fullFileName).fileName()

def stylesheet2(self):
    return """
QPlainTextEdit
{
background: #ECECEC;
color: #202020;
border: 1px solid #1EAE3D;
selection-background-color: #505050;
selection-color: #ACDED5;
}
QMenu
{
background: #F2F2F2;
color: #0E185F;
border: 1px solid #1EAE3D;
selection-background-color: #ACDED5;
} 
    """       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = myEditor()
    win.setWindowIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("application-text"))
    win.setWindowTitle("Plain Text Edit" + "[*]")
    win.setMinimumSize(640,250)
    win.showMaximized()
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        print(sys.argv[1])
        win.openFileOnStart(sys.argv[1])
    app.exec_()
```