# How to add a line count to a QLabel

Tags: python, qt5, qlabel

I am making a program that compares code files for differences, and I want each QLabel to have a line count on the side.  Like how Sublime Text or Trinket.io code editors do.  Can anyone help?  Please be clear that I am **not** amazing in PyQt5 however I *have* made programs before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create text area (textEdit) with line number in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386194/create-text-area-textedit-with-line-number-in-pyqt)

Comment: Similar but this is a __QLabel__, not a QLineEdit.  Thanks though! :D

Comment: Well, both QLabel and QLineEdit share the same functions (e.g. setText), so the previous link is a good starter.

Comment: Ahhh... thanks @Demi-Lune.